# Somehow can't prevent name duplication

Tags: mysql

I recently ran into some trouble with my registration system, I've tried to prevent name duplication in a lot of ways, And already browsed stackoverflow aswell.
But i can't seem to find the solution.

Here is my code

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['registerBtn']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $errors = array();
        $checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total from FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($checkUsername > 0)
        {
            $errors['Username is already taken'];
        }
        if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 15)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Username Must Be  Alphanumberic And 4-15 characters in length';
        }
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
        }
        if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($rpassword) || empty($email))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Please fill in all fields';
        }
        if ($password != $rpassword)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';
        }
        if (empty($errors))
        {
            $insertUser = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, :username, :password, :email, 0, 0, 0, 0)");
            $insertUser -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password), ':email' => $email));
            echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>SUCCESS: </strong>User has been registered.  Redirecting....</p></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=login.php">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong>ERROR:</strong><br />';
            foreach($errors as $error)
            {
                echo '-'.$error.'<br />';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your query is probably throwing an error: you've got `from` in there twice.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: **You've got `from` in there twice.**

Comment: Nevertheless, It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `UNIQUE` constraint on username as such:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(30),
    password varchar(80),
    email varchar(80),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY username (username)
)
```

Comment: How is this done? Sorry i'm fairly new in doing this

Comment: `CREATE TABLE users(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username varchar(30), password varchar(80), email varchar(80), PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY username (username)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing to `$countUsername`, not `$checkUsername`.

```
  if ($checkUsername > 0)
```

Change to

```
  if ($countUsername> 0)
```

Also, this line should be changed from:

```
 if ($checkUsername > 0)
    {
        $errors['Username is already taken'];
    }
```

To

```
 if ($checkUsername > 0)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Username is already taken';
    }
```

See below:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['registerBtn']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $errors = array();
        $checkUsername = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total from FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $checkUsername -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $countUsername = $checkUsername -> fetchColumn(0);
        $errors = [];
        if ($countUsername > 0)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Username is already taken';
        }
        if (!ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 15)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Username Must Be  Alphanumberic And 4-15 characters in length';
        }
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
        }
        if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($rpassword) || empty($email))
        {
            $errors[] = 'Please fill in all fields';
        }
        if ($password != $rpassword)
        {
            $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';
        }
        if (count($errors) > 0)
        {
            $insertUser = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, :username, :password, :email, 0, 0, 0, 0)");
            $insertUser -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => SHA1($password), ':email' => $email));
            echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>SUCCESS: </strong>User has been registered.  Redirecting....</p></div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=login.php">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong>ERROR:</strong><br />';
            foreach($errors as $error)
            {
                echo '-'.$error.'<br />';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to start doing some more debugging. Start by doing something like `echo $countUsername`; exit;` at certain parts of your code and see what the value of your variables are at runtime. Do this with a username that you know already exists. It should be very easy to find where your code is going wrong.

Comment: Is there anyway you can post an fixed version of the code sir? I'm sorry, Im all new in this.